# Angular dependency injection - useExisting of T?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I am writing a very simple directive that essentially lets me point to another class instance as the provider (don't ask me why, I know it's dumb but that's besides the point).  Therefore, I am using "useExisting" in my providers declaration.  This works of course, but I would like to not have to create a directive for every class of T.

Is there any way to do something like this:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appMyGenericDirective]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: T, multi: true}]
})
export class MyGenericDirective<T> {

}
```

Where "T" is the class I want to 'useExisting'?

Comment: I don't think a directive with type parameters makes sense: How would angular, upon encountering an `appMyGenericDirective` attribute in HTML, know which `T` to instantiate the directive for?

Comment: Right, I suppose it couldn't in the fashion that I have in my example.  However, would it be possible to provide this as a parameter to the directive?  And somehow supply that information to the useExisting: ... ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, somehow the HTML template must specify `T`. If you don't want to declare a separate directive for every T, you might try declaring a single directive that takes T as `@Input()`:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[freakyValidator]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useFactory: (freaky) => freaky.validator, deps:[FreakyValidatorDirective], multi: true}]
})
export class FreakyValidatorDirective {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  @Input()
  set freakyValidator(validatorClass) {
    this.validator = this.injector.get(validatorClass);
  }

  validator: Validator;
}
```

(the preceeding code is untested, I'm a bit unsure if the directive or its provider is instantiated first. But it's probably worth a try)